# How to prove that the walrasian demand function $x(p,w)$ is continuous in $p$ and $w$?

Tags: microeconomics, utility, consumption, walrasian

If the utility function $u$ is continuous and satisfies local nonsatiation, and walrasian demand function $x(p, w)$ is a function (i.e. always map to only single values), how to prove that $x(p,w)$ is continuous in $p$ (price vector) and $w$ (wealth)?

Comment: What are $x(p,w)$ and $w(p,w)$? Are they both the same walrasian demand function?

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo.

Comment: Look at the Theorem of the maximum: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem

Comment: @user24622 The Theorem of the Maximum will give you upper hemicontinuity of the Walrasian demand correspondence, but AFAICT this does not imply continuity (in the usual sense) even if Walrasian demand is single-valued.